# Outputting WordPress Category Description

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have an archive page that lists categories that links to a page for each category.
The problem I have is that on the single page the category description outputs with line breaks, but on the archive page it is called in a loop and this seems to output the description with no breaks or even the surrounding p tags.

This is the code I have in my archive page loop

```
<?php echo $category->description ?>
```

And this is how I output it on the single page

```
<?php
                if (is_tax()) {
                    // Show the Category Description if it is set.
                    $category_description = category_description();
                    if (!empty($category_description))
                        echo apply_filters('category_archive_meta', '<div class="taxonomy-description">' . $category_description . '</div>');
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: In your archive page try to this: `echo category_description($category->ID)`. I think this function applies some filters on the text before returning it.

Comment: I tried this but the function does not seem to work on the archive page. Nathan Dawson supplied the answer below that works. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo apply_filters('category_archive_meta', '<div class="taxonomy-description">' . wpautop( $category_description ) . '</div>');
```

Comment: Nathan, I love you man. That worked a treat, although with my code I had to change the $category_description to $category->description as it was part of a loop.